# Accessing a VSTO application-addin types from VBA (Excel)

Tags: c#, vba, excel, vsto

We have a VSTO application-addin (not a document-addin) for Excel, and we want to expose an event to VBA code so that the VBA macro can do some action when this event fires in the addin.  How can I get the VBA code to be able to subscribe to an event defined in the VSTO application-addin?

I'd think that since the addin is loaded in the Excel process, this shouldn't be too tricky, but haven't found a way yet.

BTW, using VS 2008 and Excel 2007.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

VSTO is not a DLL that can generally be called from other DLLs. VSTO is basically COM-exposed .NET code operating from within a wrapper operating from within a separate AppDomain. Although your VSTO add-in is technically a DLL that is being loaded into Excel, it operates more like a top-level EXE rather than as a DLL library exposed to other callers.

Personally, I would create a standard .NET assembly -- that is, avoid using VSTO for this -- and expose it to COM using the correct attributes. The process is well explained here: [COM Interop Exposed - Part 2](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/060309.htm), under the section titled "Exposing .NET Events to COM".

If you really insist on enabling VBA to be able to call VSTO, then you'll have to operate via the `Office.COMAddIn.Object` property which is enabled by overriding the `RequestComAddInAutomationService` method. The process is discussed in detail in the article [VSTO Add-ins, COMAddIns and RequestComAddInAutomationService](http://blogs.msdn.com/andreww/archive/2007/01/15/vsto-add-ins-comaddins-and-requestcomaddinautomationservice.aspx) by Andrew Whitechapel.

I hope this helps!

Mike

Comment: I ended up using the RequestComAddInAutomationService.  Thanks.