# Invoke a COM addin option from VBA

Tags: .net, vba, com, interop, vsto

Can I invoke an option on a COM Add-in from a VBA macro in Word or Excel 2007? The COM Add-in was written using VSTO – it adds a custom ribbon tab with a number of options that I want to execute from a VBA macro.

- I can reference the add-in using Application.COMAddIns("MyAddinName") but I can’t find an option to invoke an option.
- I’ve also played around with the Application.CommandBars collection, and can see that you can execute an option using CommandBarControl.Execute but I can’t find my command bar in the Application.CommandBars collection.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: +1 +star: I have exactly the same question and would appreciate if anyone can answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you're still interested in the solution: I've found [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreww/archive/2007/01/15/vsto-add-ins-comaddins-and-requestcomaddinautomationservice.aspx) on the web (following [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474205/accessing-a-vsto-application-addin-types-from-vba-excel)).

You can expose functionality within your Add-In by overriding the **AddIn.RequestComAddInAutomationService()** method and returning a class you want to provide.

In your situation you could define a class with a method which invokes the same code in your add-in as the ribbon button does, and expose that method to VBA.